# Select first 5 checkbox from a table by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table id="start" class="appplytblclr">
    <tr class="heading">
        <td>First coumn</td>
        <td>second column</td>
        <td>3rd column</td>
        <td>4th column</td>
        <tr>
            <tr id='1'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='2'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='3'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='4'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='5'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='6'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='7'>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
                </td>
                <td>s</td>
                <td>t</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a button that, on click, should select the first five check boxes. This is what I've tried so far:

```
$('#clickbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    var sList = "";
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        sList += $(this).val() + ",";
    });
    var comma = sList.split(",", 5);
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: What exactly you need , be more specific and Clear . Please provide a jsfiddle of your codes !

Comment: What does "but check box not checking" mean? Are you looking for the `:checked` selector? Do you want to check the first 5 checkboxes?

Comment: @Vohuman yes,I need to check the first 5 checkboxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```js
$("#selectFirstFive").on("click", function() {
  var checkBoxes = $("#start tr td :checkbox:lt(5)");//using :lt get first 5 checkboxes
  $(checkBoxes).prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));//change checkbox status based on check/uncheck
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="start" class="appplytblclr">
  <tr class="heading">
    <td>First coumn</td>
    <td>second column</td>
    <td>3rd column</td>
    <td>4th column</td>
    <tr>
      <tr id='1'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='2'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='3'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='4'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='5'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='6'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='7'>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" offval="no" value="&nbsp;">
        </td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="selectFirstFive" value="select" />
```

Comment: Suppose If want to unselect Can I use .prop("checked", false);

Comment: Correct. You can use `.prop("checked", false);`

Comment: But If I have already selected first two then,If I try to click the button it doesn't select first five.Its not an issue....

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) for this (don't forget about the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector too):

```
$(":checkbox:lt(5)")
```

Or if performance is your worry (and you're working with large lists), you can use the much more efficient JavaScript's [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for this:

```
$(':checkbox').slice(0, 5)
```

Comment: i lost some time to create code snippet before posting :)

Comment: @AlexChar Hehe, good job with the snippet :). I haven't got the hang of those things yet.